# Microsoft Word, Backslash and Yen sign

Tags: microsoft-word, language

I work for a Japanese company, and I often collaborate with my coworkers on technical documents using Microsoft Word. These documents sometimes contain file paths, which have backslashes in them. In Japanese, the backslash is displayed as a yen sign.

The problem is that sometimes I am creating documents for a Japanese audience, which means that the backslashes should be displayed as yen signs. Other times I am creating or editing a document for an English speaking audience, meaning that backslashes should be displayed as backslashes.

When my Japanese coworker creates the document, it uses yen signs, even when editing it on my PC, and when I create the document, it shows backslashes.

Is there a setting that allows me to convert my Japanese coworkers' yen signs into backslashes, when targeting an English audience?

Thanks

Comment: Does just changing the font not work? It looks like Japanese fonts (MS Mincho, MS Gothic) show \ as the Yen sign. Otherwise maybe Review tab > Language might help.

Comment: Font is "Calibri". Review>Language>Language Preferences shows Editing Language as "English (U.S) <default>", Display Language as "English <default>" and Help Language as "English <default>". The backslashes show up as yen symbols in this document. If I copy and paste one of the yens into another application, it pastes as a backslash!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this: `File>Options>Advanced>Layout Options for: "Document1"`

"Convert Backslash character into Yen sign" checkbox. Seems to apply just to individual documents. This is on Word 2013, might be different for older versions.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Microsoft Word, the best way to get around this bug is to use the `More >>` button to expose the `Format` button - then change the font to something else like Arial, then Find-and-replace `\` with `\`.

Comment: Well, this answer was marked -1. Jim is however right, so please use his trick, it works, in conjunction with baochan's